# Looking for Excel VBA solution to compare data

Tags: vba

Need to compare data in two excel files by FacilityID column. Excel A data has to be aggregated first. In Excel B, FacilityID is unique row.

Tries VLOOKUP. It's getting too confusing. Need VBA solution

Answer (score -1):

```js
Function BrowseWin(mypath As String)
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
  .InitialFileName = GetDir(mypath)
  If .Show = -1 Then
    BrowseWin = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
  Else
    BrowseWin = "-"
  End If
  End With
End Function

Function BrowseMac(mypath As String) As String
  sMacScript = "set applescript's text item delimiters to "","" " & vbNewLine & _
    "try " & vbNewLine & _
    "set theFiles to (choose file " & _
    "with prompt ""Please select a file or files"" default location alias """ & _
    mypath & """ multiple selections allowed true) as string" & vbNewLine & _
    "set applescript's text item delimiters to """" " & vbNewLine & _
    "on error errStr number errorNumber" & vbNewLine & _
    "return errorNumber " & vbNewLine & _
    "end try " & vbNewLine & _
    "return theFiles"
  BrowseMac = MacScript(sMacScript)
End Function

Function grantFileAccess(filePermissionCandidates)
  grantFileAccess = GrantAccessToMultipleFiles(filePermissionCandidates)
End Function


Public Function GetDir(File) As String
  If Application.OperatingSystem Like "*Mac*" Then
    div = ":"
  Else
    div = "\"
  End If
  x = InStrRev(File, div)
  If x = 0 Then
    GetDir = File
  Else
    GetDir = Left(File, x)
  End If
End Function


Sub ChooseOptima_Click()
  Dim startDir As String
  startDir = GetDir("/")
  If Application.OperatingSystem Like "*Mac*" Then
    Path = BrowseMac(startDir)
    If Path = "-43" Or Path = "-1700" Then

      startDir = MacScript("return (path to documents folder) as String")
      Path = BrowseMac(startDir)
      End If
    Else
      Path = BrowseWin(startDir)
    End If

  If Left(Path, 1) <> "-" Then
    Range("Optimafile") = Path
    Range("C6").Select
    End If
End Sub

Sub ChooseCRC_Click()
  Dim startDir As String
  startDir = GetDir("/")
  If Application.OperatingSystem Like "*Mac*" Then
    Path = BrowseMac(startDir)
    If Path = "-43" Or Path = "-1700" Then

      startDir = MacScript("return (path to documents folder) as String")
      Path = BrowseMac(startDir)
      End If
    Else
      Path = BrowseWin(startDir)
    End If

  If Left(Path, 1) <> "-" Then
    Range("Crcfile") = Path
    Range("A9").Select
    End If
End Sub


Sub LoadReports()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
  ResultPath = Range("Optimafile").Value
  grantAccessReq = Application.OperatingSystem Like "*Mac*"

  If grantAccessReq Then
    filePermissionCandidates = Array(NormPath, ExprPath)
    grantFileAccess (filePermissionCandidates)
    End If
CopyToReport (ResultPath)
    End With
End Sub


Sub CopyToReport(OptimaPath As String)
Dim Sheet1, Sheet2 As Worksheet
Dim CrcPath, File1, File2 As String

File1 = Right$(OptimaPath, Len(OptimaPath) - InStrRev(OptimaPath, "\"))

CrcPath = Range("CrcFile").Value
File2 = Right$(CrcPath, Len(CrcPath) - InStrRev(CrcPath, "\"))

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

  For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name = "Optima Blue" Then
        Sheets("Optima Blue").Delete
    End If
  Next
  For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name = "Optima Green" Then
        Sheets("Optima Green").Delete
    End If
  Next
  For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name = "CRC Limit" Then
        Sheets("CRC Limit").Delete
    End If
  Next
    For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name = "CRC Usage" Then
        Sheets("CRC Usage").Delete
    End If
  Next
  For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name = "Result Limit" Then
        Sheets("Result Limit").Delete
    End If
  Next
  For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name = "Result Usage" Then
        Sheets("Result Usage").Delete
    End If
  Next
  For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name = "CRC Usage Consolidated" Then
        Sheets("CRC Usage Consolidated").Delete
    End If
  Next
    For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name = "CRC Limit Consolidated" Then
        Sheets("CRC Limit Consolidated").Delete
    End If
  Next
 
 Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Workbooks.Open (OptimaPath)
   Set Sheet1 = Workbooks(File1).Worksheets(1)
   MakeOptimaBlueSheet
   MakeOptimaGreenSheet
   CloseBook (File1)
   
   Workbooks.Open (CrcPath)
   Set Sheet2 = Workbooks(File2).Worksheets("CRC")
   
   MakeCRCSheetLimit
   MakeCRCSheetUsage
   
   
   
   CloseBook (File2)
   
   MakeCRCSheetUsageConsolidated
   
   MakeCRCSheetLimitConsolidated
   
   MakeResultOptimaBlue
   
   MakeResultOptimaGreen
   
   MakeResultLimitReport
   
   MakeResultUsageReport
   
   
End Sub

Sub MakeOptimaBlueSheet()
dlastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
Dim rng, aRng, bRng As Range
Dim i, a, hSearch, head, headerCount As Integer

Set FirstCellExclude = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("FirstCellExcludeHeader")
Set SecondCellExclude = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("SecondCellExcludeHeader")
Set OptimaBlueHeaders = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("OptimaBlueHeaders")
Set FindHeaders = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:ZZ1")


Set u = Union(FirstCellExclude, OptimaBlueHeaders, SecondCellExclude)

  For Each fcell In FindHeaders
    For Each oCell In u
        If IsEmpty(fcell) Or IsEmpty(oCell) Then
        ElseIf fcell = oCell Then
            If Not IsEmpty(strRange) Then strRange = strRange + ","
            Cell_Add = Split(fcell.Address, "$")
            strRange = strRange + Cell_Add(1) + "1:" + Cell_Add(1) + CStr(dlastRow)
            headerCount = headerCount + 1
        Else
        End If
    Next oCell
Next fcell


 ActiveSheet.Range(strRange).Select
 Selection.Copy
    
 With ThisWorkbook
        Set ws = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
        ws.Name = "Optima Blue"
        ws.Paste

        
        Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set ExcludeRng = ws2.Range("FirstCellValues")
        exclLastRow = ws2.Range("FirstCellValues").Rows.Count
        
        Set searchFilterLetter = ws.Range("A1:Z1")
        For Each gcell In searchFilterLetter
            If IsEmpty(gcell) Then
            ElseIf gcell = FirstCellExclude.Value Then
                Cell_Add = Split(gcell.Address, "$")
                FilterLetter = Cell_Add(1)
                Debug.Print FilterLetter
            Else
            End If
        Next gcell
        
        For i = ws.Range(FilterLetter + "2:" & FilterLetter & dlastRow & " ").Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
          For a = exclLastRow To 1 Step -1
          
            If IsEmpty(ws.Cells(i, FilterLetter)) Or IsEmpty(ExcludeRng.Cells(a, 1)) Then
            ElseIf ws.Cells(i, FilterLetter) = ExcludeRng.Cells(a, 1) Then
                ws.Cells(i, FilterLetter).EntireRow.Delete
            Else
            End If
          Next a
        Next i
        
        ws.Range(FilterLetter + "1:" & FilterLetter & dlastRow & " ").Delete
        
        
        Set searchFilterLetter = ws.Range("A1:Z1")
        For Each gcell In searchFilterLetter
            If IsEmpty(gcell) Then
            ElseIf gcell = SecondCellExclude.Value Then
                Cell_Add = Split(gcell.Address, "$")
                FilterLetter = Cell_Add(1)
                Debug.Print FilterLetter
            Else
            End If
        Next gcell
        
        Set ExcludeRng2 = ws2.Range("SecondCellValues")
        exclLastRow2 = ws2.Range("SecondCellValues").Rows.Count
        
        
        For i = ws.Range(FilterLetter + "2:" & FilterLetter & dlastRow & " ").Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
          For a = exclLastRow2 To 1 Step -1
            If IsEmpty(ws.Cells(i, FilterLetter)) Or IsEmpty(ExcludeRng2.Cells(a, 1)) Then
            ElseIf ws.Cells(i, FilterLetter) = ExcludeRng2.Cells(a, 1) Then
                ws.Cells(i, FilterLetter).EntireRow.Delete
            Else
            End If
          Next a
        Next i
        
        ws.Range(FilterLetter + "1:" & FilterLetter & dlastRow & " ").Delete

        ws.Range("G1") = "Optima Blue Total"
        ws.Range("G2").Formula = "=B2+C2+D2+E2+F2"
        ws.Range("G2").Copy
        ws.Range("G3:G" & dlastRow & " ").PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
        ws.Range("G2:G" & dlastRow & " ").NumberFormat = "#,##0"

        For Each rng In ws.Range("G2:G" & dlastRow & " ")
            If rng.HasFormula Then
                rng.Formula = rng.Value
            End If
        Next rng
        
        ws.Range("B:F").Delete
        
    End With
End Sub

Sub MakeOptimaGreenSheet()
dlastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
Dim rng As Range
Dim i, a, hSearch, head, headerCount As Integer

Set FirstCellExclude = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("FirstCellExcludeHeader")
Set SecondCellExclude = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("SecondCellExcludeHeader")
Set OptimaGreenHeaders = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("OptimaGreenHeaders")
Set FindHeaders = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:ZZ1")

Set u = Union(FirstCellExclude, SecondCellExclude, OptimaGreenHeaders)

  For Each fcell In FindHeaders
    For Each oCell In u
        If IsEmpty(fcell) Or IsEmpty(oCell) Then
        ElseIf fcell = oCell Then
            If Not IsEmpty(strRange) Then strRange = strRange + ","
            Cell_Add = Split(fcell.Address, "$")
            strRange = strRange + Cell_Add(1) + "1:" + Cell_Add(1) + CStr(dlastRow)
            headerCount = headerCount + 1
        Else
        End If
    Next oCell
Next fcell

  ActiveSheet.Range(strRange).Select
 Selection.Copy
 
 With ThisWorkbook
        Set ws = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
        ws.Name = "Optima Green"
        ws.Paste
        
        Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set ExcludeRng = ws2.Range("FirstCellValues")
        exclLastRow = ws2.Range("FirstCellValues").Rows.Count

        Set searchFilterLetter = ws.Range("A1:Z1")
        For Each gcell In searchFilterLetter
            If IsEmpty(gcell) Then
            ElseIf gcell = FirstCellExclude.Value Then
                Cell_Add = Split(gcell.Address, "$")
                FilterLetter = Cell_Add(1)
                Debug.Print FilterLetter
            Else
            End If
        Next gcell
        
        For i = ws.Range(FilterLetter + "2:" & FilterLetter & dlastRow & " ").Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
          For a = exclLastRow To 1 Step -1
            If IsEmpty(ws.Cells(i, FilterLetter)) Or IsEmpty(ExcludeRng.Cells(a, 1)) Then
            ElseIf ws.Cells(i, FilterLetter) = ExcludeRng.Cells(a, 1) Then
                ws.Cells(i, FilterLetter).EntireRow.Delete
            Else
            End If
          Next a
        Next i
        
        ws.Range(FilterLetter + "1:" & FilterLetter & dlastRow & " ").Delete
        
        Set searchFilterLetter = ws.Range("A1:Z1")
        For Each gcell In searchFilterLetter
            If IsEmpty(gcell) Then
            ElseIf gcell = SecondCellExclude.Value Then
                Cell_Add = Split(gcell.Address, "$")
                FilterLetter = Cell_Add(1)
                Debug.Print FilterLetter
            Else
            End If
        Next gcell
        
        Set ExcludeRng2 = ws2.Range("SecondCellValues")
        exclLastRow2 = ws2.Range("SecondCellValues").Rows.Count
        
        For i = ws.Range(FilterLetter + "2:" & FilterLetter & dlastRow & " ").Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
          For a = exclLastRow2 To 1 Step -1
            If IsEmpty(ws.Cells(i, FilterLetter)) Or IsEmpty(ExcludeRng2.Cells(a, 1)) Then
            ElseIf ws.Cells(i, FilterLetter) = ExcludeRng2.Cells(a, 1) Then
                ws.Cells(i, FilterLetter).EntireRow.Delete
            Else
            End If
          Next a
        Next i
        
        ws.Range(FilterLetter + "1:" & FilterLetter & dlastRow & " ").Delete
        
        ws.Range("G1") = "Optima Green Total"
        ws.Range("G2").Formula = "=B2+C2+D2+E2+F2"
        ws.Range("G2").Copy
        ws.Range("G3:G" & dlastRow & " ").PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
        ws.Range("G2:G" & dlastRow & " ").NumberFormat = "#,##0"
        
        For Each rng In ws.Range("G2:G" & dlastRow & " ")
            If rng.HasFormula Then
                rng.Formula = rng.Value
            End If
        Next rng
        
        ws.Range("B:F").Delete
        
    End With
End Sub

Sub MakeCRCSheetLimit()
dlastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
Dim rng As Range
Dim i, a, hSearch, head, headerCount As Integer

Set FirstCrcFilter = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("FirstCrcFilterHeader")
Set SecondCrcFilter = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("SecondCrcFilterHeader")
Set CrcLimitHeaders = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("CrcLimitHeaders")
Set FindHeaders = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:ZZ1")

Set u = Union(CrcLimitHeaders, FirstCrcFilter, SecondCrcFilter)

  For Each fcell In FindHeaders
    For Each oCell In u
        If IsEmpty(fcell) Or IsEmpty(oCell) Then
        ElseIf fcell = oCell Then
            If Not IsEmpty(strRange) Then strRange = strRange + ","
            Cell_Add = Split(fcell.Address, "$")
            strRange = strRange + Cell_Add(1) + "1:" + Cell_Add(1) + CStr(dlastRow)
            headerCount = headerCount + 1
        Else
        End If
    Next oCell
Next fcell

 ActiveSheet.Range(strRange).Select
 Selection.Copy
 
 With ThisWorkbook
        Set ws = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
        ws.Name = "CRC Limit"
        ws.Paste
        
        Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set ExcludeRng = ws2.Range("FirstCrcFilterValues")
        exclLastRow = ws2.Range("FirstCrcFilterValues").Rows.Count
        
        Set searchFilterLetter = ws.Range("A1:Zz1")
        For Each gcell In searchFilterLetter
            If IsEmpty(gcell) Then
            ElseIf gcell = FirstCrcFilter Then
                Cell_Add = Split(gcell.Address, "$")
                FilterLetter = Cell_Add(1)
            Else
            End If
        Next gcell
        
        For i = ws.Range(FilterLetter + "2:" & FilterLetter & dlastRow & " ").Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
          For a = exclLastRow To 1 Step -1
            If IsEmpty(ws.Cells(i, FilterLetter)) Or IsEmpty(ExcludeRng.Cells(a, 1)) Then
            ElseIf ws.Cells(i, FilterLetter) = ExcludeRng.Cells(a, 1) Then
                ws.Cells(i, FilterLetter).EntireRow.Delete
                
            Else
            End If
          Next a
        Next i
        
        ws.Range(FilterLetter + "1:" & FilterLetter & dlastRow & " ").Delete
        
        Set ExcludeRng2 = ws2.Range("SecondCrcFilterValues")
        exclLastRow2 = ExcludeRng2.Rows.Count
        
        Set searchFilterLetter = ws.Range("A1:Zz1")
        For Each gcell In searchFilterLetter
            If IsEmpty(gcell) Then
            ElseIf gcell = SecondCrcFilter Then
                Cell_Add = Split(gcell.Address, "$")
                FilterLetter = Cell_Add(1)
            Else
            End If
        Next gcell
        
        For i = ws.Range(FilterLetter + "2:" & FilterLetter & dlastRow & " ").Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
          For a = exclLastRow2 To 1 Step -1
          Debug.Print ws.Cells(i, FilterLetter), ExcludeRng2.Cells(a, 1)
            If IsEmpty(ws.Cells(i, FilterLetter)) Or IsEmpty(ExcludeRng2.Cells(a, 1)) Then
            ElseIf ws.Cells(i, FilterLetter) = ExcludeRng2.Cells(a, 1) Then
                ws.Cells(i, FilterLetter).EntireRow.Delete
            Else
            End If
            Next a
        Next i
        
        ws.Range(FilterLetter + "1:" & FilterLetter & dlastRow & " ").Delete
        
        ws.Range("B2:B" & dlastRow & " ").NumberFormat = "#,##0"

 End With
    
End Sub

Sub MakeCRCSheetUsage()

dlastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
Dim rng As Range
Dim i, a, hSearch, head, headerCount As Integer

Set FirstCrcFilter = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("FirstCrcFilterHeader")
Set SecondCrcFilter = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("SecondCrcFilterHeader")
Set CrcLimitHeaders = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("CrcUsageHeaders")
Set FindHeaders = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:ZZ1")

Set u = Union(CrcLimitHeaders, FirstCrcFilter, SecondCrcFilter)

  For Each fcell In FindHeaders
    For Each oCell In u
        If IsEmpty(fcell) Or IsEmpty(oCell) Then
        ElseIf fcell = oCell Then
            If Not IsEmpty(strRange) Then strRange = strRange + ","
            Cell_Add = Split(fcell.Address, "$")
            strRange = strRange + Cell_Add(1) + "1:" + Cell_Add(1) + CStr(dlastRow)
            headerCount = headerCount + 1
        Else
        End If
    Next oCell
Next fcell

 ActiveSheet.Range(strRange).Select
 Selection.Copy
 
 With ThisWorkbook
        Set ws = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
        ws.Name = "CRC Usage"
        ws.Paste
        
        Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set ExcludeRng = ws2.Range("FirstCrcFilterValues")
        exclLastRow = ws2.Range("FirstCrcFilterValues").Rows.Count
        
        Set searchFilterLetter = ws.Range("A1:Zz1")
        For Each gcell In searchFilterLetter
            If IsEmpty(gcell) Then
            ElseIf gcell = FirstCrcFilter Then
                Cell_Add = Split(gcell.Address, "$")
                FilterLetter = Cell_Add(1)
            Else
            End If
        Next gcell
        
        For i = ws.Range(FilterLetter + "2:" & FilterLetter & dlastRow & " ").Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
          For a = exclLastRow To 1 Step -1
            If IsEmpty(ws.Cells(i, FilterLetter)) Or IsEmpty(ExcludeRng.Cells(a, 1)) Then
            ElseIf ws.Cells(i, FilterLetter) = ExcludeRng.Cells(a, 1) Then
                ws.Cells(i, FilterLetter).EntireRow.Delete
            Else
            End If
          Next a
        Next i
        
        ws.Range(FilterLetter + "1:" & FilterLetter & dlastRow & " ").Delete
        
        Set ExcludeRng2 = ws2.Range("SecondCrcFilterValues")
        exclLastRow2 = ExcludeRng2.Rows.Count
        
        Set searchFilterLetter = ws.Range("A1:Zz1")
        For Each gcell In searchFilterLetter
            If IsEmpty(gcell) Then
            ElseIf gcell = SecondCrcFilter Then
                Cell_Add = Split(gcell.Address, "$")
                FilterLetter = Cell_Add(1)
            Else
            End If
        Next gcell
        
        For i = ws.Range(FilterLetter + "2:" & FilterLetter & dlastRow & " ").Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
          For a = exclLastRow2 To 1 Step -1
            If IsEmpty(ws.Cells(i, FilterLetter)) Or IsEmpty(ExcludeRng2.Cells(a, 1)) Then
            ElseIf ws.Cells(i, FilterLetter) = ExcludeRng2.Cells(a, 1) Then
                ws.Cells(i, FilterLetter).EntireRow.Delete
            Else
            End If
          Next a
        Next i
        
        ws.Range(FilterLetter + "1:" & FilterLetter & dlastRow & " ").Delete
        
        ws.Range("B2:B" & dlastRow & " ").NumberFormat = "#,##0"
 End With
End Sub

Sub MakeCRCSheetUsageConsolidated()
 Dim CRCSheetUsageConsolidated As Worksheet, Result As Worksheet
 Dim ConsolidateRangeArray As Variant
 
 Set CRCSheetUsageConsolidated = Sheets("CRC Usage")
 CRCSheetUsageConsolidated.Select
 dlastRow = CRCSheetUsageConsolidated.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
 CRCSheetUsageConsolidated.Select
 CRCSheetUsageConsolidated.Range("A1:A" & dlastRow & " ").Select
 Selection.Copy
  
 With ThisWorkbook
        Set ws = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
        ws.Name = "CRC Usage Consolidated"

        Selection.Consolidate Sources:= _
        "'CRC Usage'!R1C1:R" & dlastRow & "C2", Function:= _
        xlSum, TopRow:=True, LeftColumn:=True, CreateLinks:=False
    End With
    
End Sub

Sub MakeCRCSheetLimitConsolidated()
 Dim CRCSheetLimitConsolidated As Worksheet, Result As Worksheet
 Dim ConsolidateRangeArray As Variant
 
 Set CRCSheetLimitConsolidated = Sheets("CRC Limit")
 CRCSheetLimitConsolidated.Select
 dlastRow = CRCSheetLimitConsolidated.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
 CRCSheetLimitConsolidated.Select
 CRCSheetLimitConsolidated.Range("A1:A" & dlastRow & " ").Select
 Selection.Copy
  
 With ThisWorkbook
        Set ws = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
        ws.Name = "CRC Limit Consolidated"

        Selection.Consolidate Sources:= _
        "'CRC Limit'!R1C1:R" & dlastRow & "C2", Function:= _
        xlSum, TopRow:=True, LeftColumn:=True, CreateLinks:=False
        
    End With
    
End Sub

Sub MakeResultOptimaBlue()
 Dim OptimaBlue As Worksheet, Result As Worksheet
 Dim ConsolidateRangeArray As Variant
 
 Set OptimaBlue = Sheets("Optima Blue")
 OptimaBlue.Select
 dlastRow = OptimaBlue.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
 OptimaBlue.Range("A1:A" & dlastRow & " ").Select
 Selection.Copy
 
 With ThisWorkbook
    
    Set ws = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
    ws.Name = "Result Limit"

    Selection.Consolidate Sources:= _
        "'Optima Blue'!R1C1:R" & dlastRow & "C2", Function:= _
        xlSum, TopRow:=True, LeftColumn:=True, CreateLinks:=False
End With

End Sub

Sub MakeResultOptimaGreen()
 Dim OptimaGreen As Worksheet, Result As Worksheet
 Dim ConsolidateRangeArray As Variant
 
 Set OptimaGreen = Sheets("Optima Green")
 OptimaGreen.Select
 dlastRow = OptimaGreen.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
 OptimaGreen.Range("A1:A" & dlastRow & " ").Select
 Selection.Copy
 
 With ThisWorkbook
    
    Set ws = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
    ws.Name = "Result Usage"

    Selection.Consolidate Sources:= _
        "'Optima Green'!R1C1:R" & dlastRow & "C2", Function:= _
        xlSum, TopRow:=True, LeftColumn:=True, CreateLinks:=False
    
End With

End Sub

Sub MakeResultLimitReport()
  Dim shOptima As Worksheet, shCrc As Worksheet, shResult As Worksheet
  Dim aRng, bRng As Range
  Dim Fnd As Range
  Dim ListObject As ListObject
  
  Set shOptima = Sheets("Optima Blue")
  Set shCrc = Sheets("CRC Limit Consolidated")
  Set shResult = Sheets("Result Limit")
  
  bLastRow = shResult.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  aLastRow = shCrc.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  Set aRng = shCrc.Range("A2:A" & aLastRow & "") '127
  Set bRng = shResult.Range("A2:A" & bLastRow & "") '71
 
  
  For Each aCell In aRng
    For Each bcell In bRng
        If aCell Is Nothing Or bcell Is Nothing Then
        ElseIf aCell.Text = bcell.Text Then
            bcell.Offset(0, 2).Formula = "='CRC Limit Consolidated'!" & aCell.Offset(0, 1).Address & " "
        Else
        End If
    Next bcell
Next aCell
    

    shResult.Range("D2").Formula = "=IF(B2=0,IF(C2=0,0,abs(((B2-C2)/C2)*100)),abs(((C2-B2)/B2)*100))"
    shResult.Range("D2").Copy
    shResult.Range("D3:D" & bLastRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
    shResult.Range("D2:D" & bLastRow).NumberFormat = "#,##0"
    
    shResult.Range("D2:D" & bLastRow).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
    shResult.Activate
    shResult.Range("A1") = "Facility ID"
    shResult.Range("D1") = "Diff in percent"
    shResult.Range("C1") = "CRC Limit"
    shResult.Range("B2:D" & bLastRow & " ").NumberFormat = "#,##0"
    
    shOptima.Range("E1:g1").Interior.ColorIndex = 35
    
    Range("A1:G" & bLastRow).EntireColumn.AutoFit
    
    Range("A2:D" & bLastRow).Sort key1:=Range("D2:D" & bLastRow), order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo
    
    Set ListObject = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("A1").CurrentRegion, , xlYes)
    With ListObject
        .Name = "Table4"
        .TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium5"
    End With
    
    
End Sub

Sub MakeResultUsageReport()
  Dim shOptima As Worksheet, shCrc As Worksheet, shResult As Worksheet
  Dim aRng, bRng As Range
  Dim Fnd As Range
  Dim ListObject As ListObject
  
  Set shOptima = Sheets("Optima Green")
  Set shCrc = Sheets("CRC Usage Consolidated")
  Set shResult = Sheets("Result Usage")
  
  bLastRow = shResult.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  aLastRow = shCrc.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  Set aRng = shCrc.Range("A2:A" & aLastRow & "")
  Set bRng = shResult.Range("A2:A" & bLastRow & "")
 
  
  For Each aCell In aRng
    For Each bcell In bRng
        If aCell Is Nothing Or bcell Is Nothing Then
        ElseIf aCell.Text = bcell.Text Then
            bcell.Offset(0, 2).Formula = "='CRC Usage Consolidated'!" & aCell.Offset(0, 1).Address & " "
        Else
        End If
    Next bcell
Next aCell
    
    shResult.Range("D2").Formula = "=IF(B2=0,IF(C2=0,0,abs(((B2-C2)/C2)*100)),abs(((C2-B2)/B2)*100))"
    shResult.Range("D2").Copy
    shResult.Range("D3:D" & bLastRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
    shResult.Range("D2:D" & bLastRow).NumberFormat = "#,##0"
    
    shResult.Range("D2:D" & bLastRow).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
    shResult.Activate
    shResult.Range("A1") = "Facility ID"
    shResult.Range("D1") = "Diff in percent"
    shResult.Range("C1") = "CRC Usage"
    shResult.Range("B2:D" & bLastRow & " ").NumberFormat = "#,##0"
    
    shOptima.Range("E1:g1").Interior.ColorIndex = 35
    
    Range("A1:G" & bLastRow).EntireColumn.AutoFit
    
    Range("A2:D" & bLastRow).Sort key1:=Range("D2:D" & bLastRow), order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo
    
    Set ListObject = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("A1").CurrentRegion, , xlYes)
    With ListObject
        .Name = "Table4"
        .TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium4"
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub

Sub CloseBook(File As String)
    Workbooks(File).Close savechanges:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
 CommandButton1.Enabled = (Range("Optimafile").Value <> "" And Range("CrcFile").Value <> "")
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
LoadReports
End Sub